# Como representar datos en EJS

Tags: nodejs, ejs

Estoy aprendiendo a usar nodejs con ejs y tuve un inconveniente, realice un controlador con 2 querys, el primero es para representar todos los datos de la bd en ejs y el segundo es para preguntar si un dato de una columna (en este caso la columna "codigo") se repite que me muestre cuantas veces se repite, este es el codigo:

```
controller.list = (req, res) => {
const query1 = "SELECT * FROM usuarios"
const query2 = "SELECT codigo, COUNT(codigo) FROM usuarios GROUP BY codigo"
req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    conn.query(query1, (err, usuarios) => {
        if(err){
            res.json(err)
        }
        conn.query( query2, (err, usado) => {
            if(err){
                res.json(err)
            }
            res.render("usuarios", {
                data: usuarios,
                count: usado
            })
        })
    })
})
```

}

Estuve revisando y las 2 consultas sql y estan bien, pude representar todos los datos de "data" en ejs por lo que me muestra toda la informacion de mi bd pero no se como mostrar tambien el resultado de "count" para que me diga cuantas veces un dato de la columna "codigo" se repite, este es el codigo que uso en ejs:

```
<% if (data) { %>
                    <% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= (i+1) %></td>
                            <td><%= data[i].nombre%></td>
                            <td><%= data[i].tipo_de_servicio %></td>
                            <td><%= data[i].codigo %></td>
                            <td>AQUI VA EL COUNT</td>
                            <td><%= moment(data[i].fecha_de_salida).format(shortDateFormat)%></td>
                            <td><%= moment(data[i].fecha_de_salida).diff(moment(), "hour") %> horas </td>
                        </tr>
                    <% } %>
                <% } %>
```